# Video editor Speed Control adds extra frames?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've got a small clip (that is a chunk broken off from a larger clip), say 32 frames that I want to run at 1/2 the speed in the video editor. I apply the speed control effect to it, check the box with "stretch to input strip length" and then change the strip length to 64. However, when I play the clip it plays the original 32 frames normally, and then just added 32 more frames from the larger clip the smaller one came frome.

How do I make the original 32 frames run at 1/2 speed and not just add more frames from the original source? Am I doing something totally wrong here or maybe a missed setting?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Use the Multiply or Speed Factor setting. This stretching doesn't work reliably, I had this problem before...

Comment: Thanks, yeah seems to work without that bug when stretching is not selected.

Comment: It may be that you have to press the Refresh Sequencer button (at the bottom of the VSE timeline window) to make the Stretch Effect work correctly.